# WEB API .NET Action with custom endpoint names

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

So I've set up a backend in .NET and the basic HTTP calls are working. Now I need an alternative method that will not search by ID but by a property, so i want to make a REST call with a different property at the end.

Here are the 2 methods of my controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetCategory(int id)
{
    var category = _productService.GetCategoryById(id);

    if (category == null) return NotFound();
    var dto = CategoryToDto(category);
    return Ok(dto);
}


public IHttpActionResult GetCategoryByName(string name)
{
    var category = _productService.GetCategoryByName(name);

    if(category == null) return NotFound();
    var dto = CategoryToDto(category);
    return Ok(dto);
}
```

My API config is configured as follow: `/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

So the first call works with this call: `/api/category/getcategory/2`

When I try the second method with this call : `/api/category/getcategorybyname/Jewelry`

I get an error saying that no action in my controller matches the request.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default routing config has an optional parameter with a restraint of type int. Passing "jewelry" does not satisfy that constraint.

The easiest fix is to apply the RouteAttribute over the action and specify the paramters that way.

```
[Route("api/category/getcategorybyname/{name}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCategoryByName(string name)
```

Make sure your `WebConfig.cs` file has attribute routing enabled with line

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

You can also shorten the action name in `RouteAttribute` by applying a `RoutePrefix("api/category")` to your controller and then stripping that part from the `Route` attribute on the action.

Comment: You can even make your endpoints the same (which would feel more RESTful). [Route("api/categories/{int:id}] by specifying the type with the parameter, .NET can resolve the correct action.

Answer (score 4):

You can also create a **RoutePrefix** rule that applies to all actions in the controller, and then apply the specific **Route** for every action:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/nestedSet")] //<<======
public class NestedSetController : ApiController
{
    [Route("myaction01")] //<<======
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<int> Myaction01_differentName()
    {
       //the call will be: http://mydomain/api/nestedSet/myaction01
       //code here...
       return 0;
    }


    [Route("myaction02")] //<<======
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<int> Myaction02_differentName()
    {
       //the call will be: http://mydomain/api/nestedSet/myaction02
       //code here...
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to decorate your 2nd method with Route attribute

```
[Route("GetCategoryByName")]
```

Then in the browser call this name.